# Core Data Error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm following this book tutorial to learn core data (Apress Pro Core Date for iOS 2nd Edition). And I thought I was following correctly but I ran into an error I dont know how to solve. The code is posted [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81707637/OrgChart.zip).

I'm interested not only in the correction to the problem, but the steps you took to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is "Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model", so that indicates there's something wrong with your `managedObjectModel` method.

First off, you named your model file as "Model", but the method is looking for one called "OrgChart", so either rename your model file or change the name in the `managedObjectModel` method.

Afterwards, it still doesn't work and setting a breakpoint in the `managedObjectModel` method reveals that it is actually never called. That's because you have a typo there, you've called the method `mangedObjectModel` instead of `managedObjectModel`. After adding the missing `a`, your app should run.